# Help with dynamic page cache

Tags: 8, caching

I have a page generated by a custom module that contains two sections:

- Product info
- Recently viewed products

The product info only changes when the product is updated.

Recently viewed products are unique to every visitor (data is stored in `$_SESSION`).

Each section has its own render array.

```
'productinfo' => [
    // ...
    '#cache' => [
        'tags' => ['product:1234']
    ]
],
'recentlyviewed' => [
    // ...
    '#lazy_builder' => array(
      // ....
    ),
    '#create_placeholder' => TRUE,
    '#cache' => [
        'max-age' => 0
    ]
]
```

The behaviour I expect is that the dynamic page cache can cache the `productinfo` section, but the recentlyviewed would never be cached. However, if a session has not yet been started (i.e. first page view), the *entire* html page is cached to the `cache_render` DB table, and `cache_dynamic_page_cache` is always empty.

The `X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache` header is always set to `UNCACHABLE`.

How can I get the dynamic page cache to cache the product info section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has two different topics:

> 1. How can I get the dynamic page cache to cache the product info
>      section?

Set cache keys:

```
'productinfo' => [
    // ...
    '#cache' => [
        'keys' => ['mymodule', 'product', '1234'],
        'tags' => ['product:1234'],
    ],
],
```

Sections of a render array are only cached, if they have cache keys. The keys are used to build the unique cid for the cache render table.

> 2. However, if a session has not yet been started (i.e. first page view),
>      the entire html page is cached

Anonymous traffic is cached by the *Internal Page Cache*. If you start a session, the next request will be able to pass the *Internal Page Cache* and is handled by the *Dynamic Page Cache*.

Comment: OK, thanks! I saw cache keys were mentioned, but could not find any further documentation. Is there any specific naming convention, or do they just have to be unique?

Comment: There are no naming convention. I would use three keys, one for the project, so that there is no conflict with other projects, one for the type and one for the id.

Comment: The product info now gets its own render cache entry, using the keys for the cid. The dynamic page cache isn't being used, but I guess it's not needed.